# identity server 4 + AspNetCore.Identity: how to lockout after X tries?

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, identity

I'm using identityServer4 with AspNetCore.Identity.
my client are logging in using RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync function.
how can I defend myself from too many login tries?

`MaxFailedAccessAttempts` property, but it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are confusing things. So let me start with the [terminology](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/intro/terminology.html).

*What is a client?*

> A *client* is a **piece of software** that requests tokens from
>   IdentityServer.

*What is a user?*

> A *user* is a **human** that is *using a registered client* to access
>   resources.

The *client* is registered allowing certain [grant types](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html):

*Machine to Machine Communication*:

> Tokens are always requested on behalf of a client, **no** *interactive user*
>   is present.

And when a *user* is involved: *Interactive Clients*.

> This is the most common type of client scenario: web applications,
>   SPAs or native/mobile apps with *interactive users*.

When you talk about `RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync` then this indicates that you are using the *ClientCredentials* flow. A flow where a client is registered to allow the client credentials grant type.

As documented in this flow there is no interactive user present.

---

Now about the `MaxFailedAccessAttempts` property. This is part of the [lockout options](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.lockoutoptions.maxfailedaccessattempts?view=aspnetcore-3.1):

> Gets or sets the number of failed access attempts allowed before a
>   **user** is locked out, assuming lock out is enabled. Defaults to 5.

And here's the answer to why this property isn't working. The lockout options aren't relevant for the *client credentials* flow since there is no user present.

Now to answer your question: *How can I defend myself from too many login tries?*

A *client login* is not the same as a *user login*. There is no mechanism to lockout clients. If you want this functionality for a client then you'll have to extend IdentityServer.

But given your question, mentioning *AspNetCore.Identity*, it seems you should rather implement the correct flow where a *user* can login. Take a look at the [samples](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Quickstarts).

Comment: Great answer, thanks.
can you please direct me to the relevant example? i cant find it in the link attached

Comment: You may want to start with the [2_InteractiveAspNetCore](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Quickstarts/2_InteractiveAspNetCore) sample. In addition, read the mentioned [specifications](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/intro/specs.html). IdentityServer is an implementation of these specifications.

Comment: I’m probably missing something.
I downloaded this 2_InteractiveAspNetCore solution and run it, it doesn’t stop on any function in IdentityServer project.
I’m spending many hours about reading this material but it lack technical guides.
Can you direct me which class should I look for? 

I debug this solution with invalid password and it didn’t stop on any function

Comment: Make sure you start the instance of Api, IdentityServer and MvcClient. Go to the Mvc website. /home will redirect you to [AccountController.Login](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Quickstarts/2_InteractiveAspNetCore/src/IdentityServer/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs#L54) in IdentityServer (because the page is protected by endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute().RequireAuthorization).

Comment: The whole point i'm using machine to machine communication and not the mvc project. I'm using the console application which request client token